# Валидация формы(поле название компании) с подтягиванием данных

Tags: javascript, валидация

#### Ребята, нужен совет!!!

Пытаюсь устроиться на работу на должность junior Front-End. Дали задание сверстать, свалидировать форму регистрации корпоративного клиента. Практически все сделал, но вот один из пунктов для меня как для "юного" разработчика совсем темный лес.

А именно, поле "Название компании" - валидация на наличие зарегистрированной компании в сети linkedin; варианты подгружаются по мере ввода текста и отображаются в списке.

Я не прошу каких то готовых решений, я прошу подскажите хоть в каком направлении искать. Все запросы в гугле(в том числе и на английском языке)максимум предлагают валидацию регулярными выражениями. Но ничего, не слова о валидации с подтягиванием данных из базы данных компаний в сети linkedin

Подскажите где искать хоть что-то подобное. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Поройся тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232748/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-ajax-example
Там конечно не написано, где взять источник данных, но все остальное есть...

Comment: LinkedIn API...